# How to set Password Validation in react

Tags: reactjs

How to validate a password like atleast one Capital letter one special character one number and minlength 8 in react Js without use any react library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
const valid = value.length >= 8 && /[A-Z]/.test(value) && /[^a-zA-Z]/.test(value) && /[0-9]/.test(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const passwordRegExp = new RegExp(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&\.\+\*\{\]\{\[\-,;`<>':"=^#_|\/\\])(?=.*?[A-Za-z\d@$!%*+?&\.\+\*\{\]\{\[\-,;`<>':"=^#_|\/\\]).{8,}/)
const formValueFalse = 'aaabbb'
const formValueTrue = 'AaBb123$'
passwordRegExp.test(formValueFalse)
passwordRegExp.test(formValueTrue)
```